# Fortify reporting "Privacy violation" issue

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, fortify

The below code is being identified by Fortify as a vulnerability/issue of the "Privacy violation" category.

```
sbfOut.append(" validateSSN(document.form1." + name
                    + ",\" \",\" \")' " + override + "; >");
            out.println(sbfOut.toString());
        } // SN end
        else if (fieldType.equals(CoConstants.DE_ELEMENT_TYPE_TN
```

In another method I have, Fortify identified the below code block as a vulnerability issue of the "Privacy violation" category as well.

```
sbfOut.append(" <OPTION VALUE='0'>-NO DATA-</OPTION>");
        try {
            out.println(sbfOut.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            debug("Exception In coCustomTag" + ioe
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this and where exactly the issue is.

The exact message Fortify is giving:

> The method methodName() in CoCustomTag.java mishandles confidential information, which can compromise user privacy and is often illegal.

Please ignore the open braces and all, as I have put here only the portion of code identified by Fortify.

Comment: I'd have to guess but do you by any chance log data such as names etc.? I don't know fortify but "privacy violation" seems to hint at writing personal data such as names to a more permanent storage such as log files.

Comment: @Thomas here  out.println(sbfOut.toString()); is present in both portions and out is of type "JSPWriter"

Answer (score 4):

I was bothered for maybe three days or more, searching Google for any clue I could get, until I looked up into the stack trace on the bottom left of the Audit Workbench (in Fortify). The top of the stack trace suggested to me that my issue was caused by a method named `decrypt(...)`. Believe it or not, when I renamed the method, the issue disappeared.

Comment: I doubt that this will fix the issue. I guess the renaming misleads the Audit Workbench, so that the issue is not found anymore.

Comment: I had the same problem with a method called: `encrypt`

Answer (score 4):

If you believe that this issue is a false positive or u can ignore then 
Fortify Java Annotations @FortifyNotPassword, @FortifyNotPrivate can be used to indicate which fields and variables represent passwords and private data.

These annotations will tell fortify code analyzer to ignore the fields and issue is gone.

Check below for more details.

[HP Fortify -- annotating method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529255/hp-fortify-annotating-method-parameters)

Comment: I added maven dependency. it is not displaying those annotations. can you please tell me the dependency version?

Comment: it is not working. can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

If in your first code snippet HTML output is created and **`name` can be changed by the user** (e. g. by rewriting the URL) then this is a **[cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)** vulnerability issue: setting `name` to `," "," ");alert("Hi");//` may cause popping up an alert box.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But could you please explain where is the privacy violation issue here. Is it due to "out.println(sbfOut.toString());" in both cases. FYI here out is of type "JSPWriter"

Comment: Exactly, these are the places where text that is modifiable from outside becomes HTML output: `out.println(text_modifiable_from_outside)`